# How to build ffmpeg with vo-amrwbenc library?

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew

I have downloaded ffmpeg using homebrew and want to add amr-wb encoder support to it,

```
DEA.L. amr_nb               AMR-NB (Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand) (decoders: amrnb amr_nb_at libopencore_amrnb ) (encoders: libopencore_amrnb )
 D.A.L. amr_wb               AMR-WB (Adaptive Multi-Rate WideBand) (decoders: amrwb libopencore_amrwb )
```

I downloaded vo-amrbenc following the instruction here but don't understand where should I explicitly configure the build with --enable-libopencore-amrwb?
(https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Encoders)

A dumb question is that, I didn't find ./configure file under /usr/local/Cellar/ directory. I am really not an engineer and not familiar with the build and compile thing so any guidance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can just [download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/). It has `--enable-libvo-amrwbenc` for AMR-WB encoding. Put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

The [ffmpeg build script in Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb) does not currently appear to support libvo-amrwbenc. If you want to compile using Homebrew you will have to edit the Homebrew script (I guess...I've never used Homebrew). If you want to compile without using Homebrew first install libvo-amrwbenc (or whatever provides `vo-amrwbenc/enc_if.h`) then use `--enable-libvo-amrwbenc` when configuring `ffmpeg`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: macOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS) for additional information on Homebrew and compiling.

Opus audio is worth mentioning. It is a modern, flexible, free, open source format [offering better quality than AMR in all but the lowest of bitrates](https://twitter.com/kamedo2/status/907720057144328192).

Comment: Yeah, I have already done that. But --enabe-libopencore-amrwb only support amr-wb decoder, not amr-wb encoder, if I understand correctly. I want to add amr-wb encoder to my ffmpeg. According to instruction here, https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libvo_002damrwbenc.